# I'm trying to data from Firebase Firestore, but the result I'm getting is null

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to data from Firebase Firestore, but the result I'm getting is null.

This program is supposed to retrieve data for Image, Title, and Price, but it's only returning null values for the Title.

Please suggest what I should do to resolve this error.

**prouduct_add_screen.dart**

```
class _ProuductAddScreenState extends State<ProuductAddScreen> {
  final prouductNameController = TextEditingController();
  final prouductPriceController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _prouductName = '';
  String _prouductPrice = '';

  textFieldValidation() {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate() || prouductNameController != null) {
      _prouductName = prouductNameController.text.toString();
      _prouductPrice = prouductPriceController.text.toString();

      if (image != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ClothesListScreen(
                prouductImage: image!.path,
                prouductName: prouductNameController.text.toString(),
                prouductPrice: prouductPriceController.text.toString(),
              ),
            ));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Center(
              child: AppText(
                  text: "Prouduct Added",
                  textColor: AppColor.blackColor,
                  fontSize: 15.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
            backgroundColor: AppColor.grayColor3,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
            behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
            elevation: 2,
            width: 200.w,
          ),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Center(
              child: AppText(
                  text: "Please Pick Image",
                  textColor: AppColor.blackColor,
                  fontSize: 15.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
            backgroundColor: AppColor.grayColor3,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
            behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
            elevation: 2,
            width: 200.w,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  File? image;

  void _pickImageFormGallery() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (image == null) return;

    final imageTemp = File(image.path);

    setState(() {
      this.image = imageTemp;
    });
  }

  void _pickImageFormCamera() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if (image == null) return;

    final imageTemp = File(image.path);

    setState(() {
      this.image = imageTemp;
    });
  }

  Widget imageBox() {
    if (image != null) {
      return Container(
        height: 230.h,
        width: 155.w,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColor.grayColor3,
            image:
                DecorationImage(image: FileImage(image!), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        height: 230.h,
        width: 155.w,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: AppColor.grayColor3),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget pickImage() {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text("Pick an Image"),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _pickImageFormCamera();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text("Camera"),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _pickImageFormGallery();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Text("Gallery"),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          AppText(
              text: "Tap to Pick Image",
              textColor: AppColor.blackColor,
              fontSize: 15.sp,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget prouductName() {
    return AppTextFiled(
        text: "Prouduct Name",
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        controller: prouductNameController,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter your prouduct name';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onChangedValue: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _prouductName = value!;
          });
          return null;
        },
        keyboard: TextInputType.name);
  }

  Widget prouductPrice() {
    return AppTextFiled(
        text: "Prouduct Price",
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        controller: prouductPriceController,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter your prouduct price';
          }
          return null;
        },
        onChangedValue: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _prouductPrice = value!;
          });
          return null;
        },
        keyboard: TextInputType.number);
  }

  Widget loginButton() {
    return AppShadowButton(
      text: "Add Prouduct",
      onPressed: () {
        textFieldValidation();
      },
      color: AppColor.blackColor,
      textcolor: AppColor.whiteColor,
    );
  }
}
```

**clothes_list_screen.dart**

```
class ClothesListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String prouductImage;
  final String prouductName;
  final String prouductPrice;

  const ClothesListScreen(
      {super.key,
      required this.prouductImage,
      required this.prouductName,
      required this.prouductPrice});

  @override
  State<ClothesListScreen> createState() => _ClothesListScreenState();
}

class _ClothesListScreenState extends State<ClothesListScreen> {
  String clotheImage = '';
  String clotheName = '';
  String clothePrice = '';

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> gatData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('clothes').snapshots();

  Future<void> addClothesToFirestore() async {
    final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    if (clotheImage != "" || clotheName != "") {
      await firestore.collection('clothes').add({
        'image': clotheImage,
        'name': clotheName,
        'price': clothePrice,
      });
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    clotheImage = widget.prouductImage;
    clotheName = widget.prouductName;
    clothePrice = widget.prouductPrice;

    addClothesToFirestore();
  }

  Widget gridViewList() {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(overscroll: false),
      child: Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: gatData,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final clothe = snapshot.data!.docs
                      .map((doc) =>
                          Clothes.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
                      .toList();

                  return GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        mainAxisExtent: 230.h,
                        childAspectRatio: 5,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 26.h),
                    itemCount: clothe.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final isLiked = isLikedList[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Stack(children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 230.h,
                              width: 155.w,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                image: FileImage(File(clothe[index].image!)),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              top: 179.h,
                              child: Container(
                                height: 56.h,
                                width: 155.w,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: AppColor.grayColor3.withOpacity(0.74),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        AppText(
                                            text:
                                                clothe[index].title.toString(),
                                            textColor: AppColor.blackColor,
                                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                        AppText(
                                            text: "\$${clothe[index].price!}",
                                            textColor: AppColor.blackColor,
                                            fontSize: 12.sp,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        ]),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const AppLoader();
                }
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That is My Code Model.

```
class Clothes {
  String? image;
  String? title;
  String? price;

  Clothes({this.image, this.title, this.price});

  Clothes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    image = json['image'];
    title = json['title'];
    price = json['price'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

issue is because you are saving key as **name** and fetching as **title**

```
 Clothes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    image = json['image'];
    title = json['title'];
    price = json['price'];
  }

await firestore.collection('clothes').add({
        'image': clotheImage,
        'name': clotheName,
        'price': clothePrice,
      });
```

Solution: rename name to title in addClothesToFirestore() function

```
await firestore.collection('clothes').add({
            'image': clotheImage,
            'title': clotheName,
            'price': clothePrice,
          });
```

Comment: @m._e._e._t._08 if this solution worked, please accept the answer so it can help others. See [Accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)